# TexMaker - "Font Dummy" grid?

Tags: miktex, titles, texmaker

I'm a very new TeX user, I've installed MiKTeX and Texmaker. I've just started trying to write a report with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{me}
\date{now}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

and it was working for a while, but coming back to it now all it outputs in the PDF is this thing:

[image: Dummy Font?]

I'm honestly not sure what's gone wrong or what I'm even looking at.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It looks like detritus left over from a previous run.  Try getting rid of all files with the same name as your document, but with an extension other than `tex` or `pdf`.  That is, get rid of `myfile.aux`, etc, where `myfile` is the name of your document.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! :) Any advice on how to stop this from happening in the future? :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: That's fine. Is there a way for me to award Steven any rep? :) I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @V.L.Proud You can go to one of his previous questions or answers and upvote. Not sure how the community thinks about that but I am fine with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many features of TeX require multiple compilation passes to achieve a proper output.  Examples are citations, references, indices, etc.  The method used in these cases is, during the first pass, to write things to an ancillary file, which is then read and executed on a later compilation pass.  This is how, for example, a `\label` later in the document can be `\ref`erenced earlier in the document.  The typical (though not exclusive) ancillary file for many of these tasks is the `aux` file.  Others include `idx`, `bbl`, `bcf`, `nav`, etc.

If your document changes significantly, such that one of these ancillary processes is no longer required, the presence of the residual ancillary file is sufficient to interfere with the proper compilation of the revised document.  This is especially true if a prior compilation was interrupted for some reason (an error, for example).

The solution, in all cases, is to remove these ancillary files that share the same root name as your base document and recompile.