# \endcsname error (need help fast!)

Tags: bibliographies, errors, csname

I have these two error messages and I'm not sure how to solve it, any help as soon as available would be really appreciated. I'm not very good at LaTeX and I'm using it to write my dissertation. The paragraph quoted was the one I was writing up when the error message appeared. Not quite sure what is wrong with it

Thanks

```
'The laws governing generative design are the SIMP method (as highlighted above) ,the Rational approximation of Material Properties method, an interpolation scheme for a  material with two regions whereby the objective function can be solved for when the penalisation factor is set to a \cite{RAMP}.  and also linear programming to topologically optimise a design. Linear programming'
```

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.451 \bibcite{\end  }{100}
                           
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

 output.aux, line 451

Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.451 \bibcite{\end  }{100}
                           
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 22284 strings out of 480907
 411060 string characters out of 5908306
 867609 words of memory out of 5000000
 37496 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 537345 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,0n,106p,1038b,123s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: This is the error n.100... the only relevant one is the first one. If you do not give us more information, it is impossible to give an answer. Think about it: how could we know what's wrong about your code without seeing a single line of it? Anyway, just a question: if you are not good at LaTeX, why writing your thesis with it? Especially if you are in a hurry, it is not a savy decision... LaTeX requires time to master.

Comment: I was just writing up a paragraph and referencing a bibitem and it popped out of no where. I undid the recent changes but it did not seem to change the error. I tried to rename my labels as that is a common error and nothing worked.

Comment: It's a dissertation and my supervisor advised me for large reports having an interactive report would help navigating around.

Comment: I have been using it for the past 4 months and I have had other errors that have been resolvable but not this. Aside from that, do you you how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, but this is insufficient information to even start thinking to the problem.

Comment: I could provide you viewer access to the document to see if you could help spot it?https://www.overleaf.com/read/jzcknxcndzpp

Comment: If undoing your edits did not change back the result, perhaps delete the auxiliary files and recompile.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591781/texmaker-font-dummy-grid/591814#591814

Comment: Removing the .aux file is absolutely necessary since that's where the error is coming from. `\bibcite` is a command that's generated when the bibliography is typeset. Your bibliography has a lot of issues in it, beginning with the `\thebibliography{file}` command which doesn't belong there (did you mean `\bibliography{file}`?). You also didn't give the obligatory argument on your `\begin{thebibliography}` command, and between that and some of the janky markup in the bibliography items themselves, this might be how `\end` is ending up out of place in the aux file in a `\bibcite` command.

Comment: Also, I **strongly** recommend looking at the "logs and output files" listing (click the red number above your output preview) and start at the top and fix the errors one by one. Errors earlier in the document can lead to spurious errors later.

Comment: The link you provided indicates that LaTeX flagged 261 [!!] issues with your code. Is there a reason for letting these issues pile up?

Comment: Mainly due to the table formatting and  just not including dollar signs where needed with used symbols.

Comment: TeX's error recovery does not try to make the PDF usable if there is an error, it just tries to recover enough to allow syntax checking the rest of the document, so never use a PDF if there is any error reported and always fix the first error first as often later errors are spurious, generated by the error recovery.

Comment: Thanks, that is very much appreciated.

Comment: @s1709765 - I've tried to clean up your LaTeX code as much as possible; see https://www.overleaf.com/read/pbtffqxhfsxj. There should be no more outright errors. However, there are still a warning messages, related to the fact that certain objects have been given the same label, whereas other objects being cross-referenced aren't labelled. Hopefully you'll find this cleaned-up file to be a good starting point for further streamlining.

Comment: That is unbelievably kind of you. thank you so much for doing that, that has honestly been so helpful. What is your work e-mail Mico, I wanted to e-mail you something privately.